# ASP.Net: The type or namespace name 'namespace ' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: asp.net

This should be an easy fix.
I created a Linq to SQL class using SQLMetal.
I added it to my project and put it in the App_Code folder. See below
Yet intellisence is not picking up the namespace in my Default.aspx.cs code. See below.
So when I build I naturally get an error as above.
What should I do to fix this bug?

The generated Linq to SQL class in the App_Code folder begins as;

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.3053
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace RiskManNew
{
        using System.Data.Linq;
        using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Reflection;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Linq.Expressions;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System;


        public partial class RiskManNew : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
        {
...
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The Default.aspx.cs begins as

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using RiskManNew;
...
```

Intellisense does not recognise RiskManNew

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem may be that you've got a namespace called `RiskManNew` *and* a class called `RiskManNew`. It's possible to work around this, but it's not worth the hassle. Just change one of the names.

If that's *not* the problem, it may be due to `App_Code` not being picked up properly. I've certainly seen that happen before - but it will be easier to diagnose once you've fixed the naming issue.

Comment: I changed the namespace but with no joy. I also moved the class out of the App_Code folder into the base folder, but this didn't work either.